# Highstock chart not zooming to specific date range

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to zoom highstock chart on demand but for some reason its not zooming. I am using -

```
chart.xAxis[0].update({min:minDate, max:maxDate});
```

Here is a fiddle which I have created to explain the issue. On click of 'zoom' button the chart (navigator) should zoom to the date range I have specified.

http://jsfiddle.net/amit657/0xthLnkp/1/

Appreciate if anybody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `update` function you should use the `setExtremes` ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes)) function of the axis.

For example:

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(minDate, maxDate);
```

See [this updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0xthLnkp/2/) demonstration.